# PDF Printer with Preview

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

I'm often sending letters as PDF and prefer to proof read the final document to be sure embedded pictures, paragraphs etc. are correct.

Hence I am looking for a PDF Printer that will show a preview of the (about to be printed) document, similar to the way macOS does it when you do 
Print>PDF>Open in Preview.  It then should have a save/cancel choice.

Ideally free (ad-free) or with moderate (about $25-$40) one-time payment price.

Comment: I don't know if i am right but the purpose of pdf is that you will see what you gonna print so adobe reader or any browser is more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FinePrint [pdfFactory](http://fineprint.com/pdf/) opens with Preview.  You can even edit it (delete those last white pages for example).

It is a bit outside your price range though, US$50